# Are OPPCGMCS questions allowed on meta?

Tags: support

As the title says, are questions about the PPCG Minecraft server allowed on the meta site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

Meta's off topic close reason states

> This question does not appear to be about Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.

and the only relation the PPCG Minecraft server bears to PPCG is its name.

Comment: Ok. I thought so but I was just making sure.